# node.js socket.io server on os x cannot connect more than 120 clients

Tags: node.js, nginx, socket.io, osx-yosemite

I am writing socket.io-client node.js bot app in order to test performance of my socket.io based server application also running under node.

Usually the server runs ubuntu linux but I also have the same server app (node.js, nginx, socket.io) installed and configured on my local dev machine.

If I start my bot-"script" and launch 200 bots that create individual connections to the server I have no problem whatsoever if I do it to the real server(s), the linux servers.

But if I connect to my local os x based "server" I cannot really get over ~120 connections.

I get disconnects, stale sockets, and an infinite loop of disconnect/reconnect which under the standard settings of socket.io will just take longer and longer to complete (delayed reconnection attempt).

My local dev machine is under almost 0% load during such a test, so it is not related to memory or processor.

I have tried the same bot-script from a second local machine, to ensure the issue was not related to the bots running on the same machine as the server. But I get the same issue.

As soon as I point the bot-script towards the real servers I have no issues whatsoever.

When I am in the range where the issue occurs, i.e. pushing with more than 120 clients, I have tried to access my local dev-server with a browser (the real user-scenario) and refresh many times. Sometimes I get a "internal server 500".

Makes me think that maybe this is not socket.io related by rather nginx? or some other basic socket limitation on a regular os x (non server) machine?

Answer (score 3):

All the googling I did before posting this question..... 
and 3 minutes after doing so I stumbled upon the answer:

Write in terminal:

```
sysctl -a | grep somax
```

I got the answer:

```
kern.ipc.somaxconn: 128
```

so case is pretty closed I guess.

One just write in terminal:

```
sudo sysctl -w kern.ipc.somaxconn=xyz
```

where xyz is the number of connections to allow.

Found answer here: 
http://b.oldhu.com/2012/07/19/increase-tcp-max-connections-on-mac-os-x/

Comment: Nice work. Saved for future reference because I know one day it will bite me too.

Comment: Actually just changing that value I highlighted didnt seem to solve the mess. But I was at least able to conclude that the problem was not in my code, nginx or node. So I have put it to rest for a while. I will make sure to post back here once I have solved the issue for real. I have a fairly un-tweaked OS X install so I imagine a lot of people must stumble upon this issue, although maybe most people never try to bombard their PCs with thousands of connections :)

Answer (score 0):

The somaxconn value of 128 seemed a acceptable solution. But in my case changing that value didnt do it.

This post explains the solution. 
http://docs.basho.com/riak/latest/ops/tuning/open-files-limit/#Mac-OS-X

The issue is the max proccess limit and max open files limit. 
one can view these limits by writing 
ulimit -u (open docs) 
ulimit -n (max procc)

Changing them runtime did not work well for me but the link above explains how to change these values permanently for a number of popular operating systems.

After I made this change I had no problem exceeding the previous limits and my kern.ipc.somaxconn: is still 128..